# How to update multiple rows with the same value on Laravel 8?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to update a value in my database with a new value base on user input but I can't seem to make it work.

This is the code that successfully manually updates all the rows I want

```
public function updateno(Request $request){
    if(Auth::id()){
     $user_id=Auth::id();
       $data = details::where('user_id', $user_id)
                      ->where('order','pending')
                      ->update(['contactno' => 111111]);
            return redirect()->back();
    }else{
        return redirect('/login');
    }
}
```

The result

| id | user_id | name | status | order | contactno | address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 13 | John | pending | Burger | 111111 | Sta Maria |
| 2 | 13 | John | pending | Latte | 111111 | Sta Maria |
| 3 | 12 | Mikael | approved | Burger | 233333 | San Fernando |
| 4 | 13 | John | pending | Coke | 111111 | Sta Maria |

but when I try the **$request** for new user input or when they update their contact no. like the code below, it instead saves a random number **`2147483647`** which is completely different from the user input **`8917772`** I also tried **`dd($request->contactno)`** to see if the user input does retrieve it correctly and it does. That's why it makes me confused and don't know the problem or to fix it.

```
public function updateno(Request $request){
    if(Auth::id()){
     $user_id=Auth::id();
       $data = details::where('user_id', $user_id)
                      ->where('order','pending')
                      ->update(['contactno' => $request->contactno]);
            return redirect()->back();
    }else{
        return redirect('/login');
    }
}
```

The result is like this instead of the user input **`8917772`**

| id | user_id | name | status | order | contactno | address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 13 | John | pending | Burger | 2147483647 | Sta Maria |
| 2 | 13 | John | pending | Latte | 2147483647 | Sta Maria |
| 3 | 12 | Mikael | approved | Burger | 233333 | San Fernando |
| 4 | 13 | John | pending | Coke | 2147483647 | Sta Maria |

Comment: `2147483647` isn't actually a random number. It's the maximum size for a 32-bit integer. It suggests that you're trying to write a larger number to the field than it can support, and the value is being limited to `PHP_INT_MAX`. What's the data type for the `contactno` field?

Comment: Thank you @fubar for pointing that out I thought that my problem is in the code not realizing the data type I declared int in my database is indeed the problem and is now fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you need to change the type of the field "contactno" to `BIGINT (20)` or something else, so the field can store values.

Comment: Thank you so much @eng this solved my problem by turning the data type int in my database to 'BIGINT(20)', now it's storing the exact same data being inserted without a problem